# How to create a string "replace all" function?

Tags: javascript

Every article or question I've seen pretty much says, just use:

```
str.replace(/yourstring/g, 'whatever');
```

But I want to use a variable in place of "yourstring". Then people say, just use `new RegExp(yourvar, 'g')`. The problem with that is that `yourvar` may contain special characters, and I don't want it to be treated like a regex.

So how do we do this properly?

---

Example input:

```
'a.b.'.replaceAll('.','x')
```

Desired output:

```
'axbx'
```

Comment: You want to not treat regex like regex? Can you define the types of input you'd like to provide? Will you want regex-functionality, or is it just a string of literal characters, `"ABc34*\d/4h"` you want to work with/replace?

Comment: @DavidThomas: Any input. All I want is a simple function that replaces *all* instances of "x" with "y", not just the first one, as `string.replace` does.

Comment: `'a.b.c'.split('.').join('x')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can split and join.

```
var str = "this is a string this is a string this is a string";

str = str.split('this').join('that');

str; // "that is a string that is a string that is a string";
```

Comment: This solution seems to be significantly faster, so you get the check. Wouldn't have thought of doing this; thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From http://cwestblog.com/2011/07/25/javascript-string-prototype-replaceall/

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(target, replacement) {
  return this.split(target).join(replacement);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can escape your `yourvar` variable using the following method:

```
function escapeRegExp(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

Comment: I think you went a little excessive on the backslashes. When inside a character set, you don't need to escape much. Nevertheless, this is a viable solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

[XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) provides a function for escaping regular expression characters in strings:

```
var input = "$yourstring!";
var pattern = new RegExp(XRegExp.escape(input), "g");
console.log("This is $yourstring!".replace(pattern, "whatever"));
// logs "This is whatever"
```

Comment: I don't really want the whole library, so I dug through the source: `nativ.replace.call(str, /[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");` Library does look neat though.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1

```
RegExp.escape = function(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}

String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replace) {
    return this.replace(new RegExp(RegExp.escape(search),'g'), replace);
};
```

## Solution 2

```
'a.b.c.'.split('.').join('x');
```

---

[jsPerf Test](http://jsperf.com/string-replaceall2)